# In React MUI X, Date Picker how to enable only last day of month

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

In React MUI X, Date Picker how to enable only last day of month.

I do see there are options for disable of specific dates, month and year but not enable. Can someone help on this please

Comment: Tangential: if you can only choose the last day of the month why do you need a date picker?

Comment: Do we have any other options in MUI X??

Comment: Why not just using a select to allow user select a month?